# Is there a function like getBackStackEntryCount in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

1. How to do getBackStackEntryCountin flutter like we do in android.
2. How to navigate the current fragment to the previous fragment in a flutter.

Comment: if you are new to "navigation" in flutter read this: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation